# Using a static library of SensibleTableView (STV) with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods

I want to use  [STV](http://sensiblecocoa.com) Standard framework which is a static libraray, closed source. I experimented with the podspec, but up to now, I didn't get it to work. The header arefound, but the .m seem to be missing.

Here is the folder structure of the framework:!

[image]

I have the podspec in the "Static Frameworks" folder.

This is the podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name = 'SensibleTableView'
s.version = '3.3.0'
s.platform = :ios
s.ios.deployment_target = '6.1'

framework_path = 'SensibleTableView.framework'
s.source_files = "#{framework_path}/Versions/A/Headers/*.h"
s.source = "#{framework_path}/Versions/A/SensibleTableView"
s.requires_arc = true
```

end

And I call the podspec in the podfile with this line:

```
 pod 'SensibleTableView', :path => "/Users/myPath/Static Frameworks/"
```

There are no error messages while installing the pod, but when building the project, I get these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCArrayOfStringsSection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SettingsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCTableViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SettingsViewController in SettingsViewController.o
   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCTableViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SettingsViewController in SettingsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've already tried out a lots of stuff, but appearently there is a part missing in the podspec? Any help appreciated.

EDIT: 
I import the podfile this way `#import <SensibleTableView/SensibleTableView.h>`

Comment: Not sure how you're including the framework since that doesn't seem to be part of the snippet above. You probably want the [`vendored_frameworks`](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html#vendored_frameworks) attribute.

Comment: @KeithSmiley: bingo, please put it to an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you're including the framework since that doesn't seem to be part of the snippet above. You probably want the [`vendored_frameworks`](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html#vendored_frameworks) attribute.

---

EDIT from the one who was asking - this is the resulting podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name = 'SensibleTableView'
s.version = '3.3.0'
s.platform = :ios
s.ios.deployment_target = '6.1'
s.vendored_frameworks = 'SensibleTableView.framework'
s.requires_arc = true
end
```